# How do I render a HTML file in a subfolder?

Tags: node.js, express

Within my "views" folder, i have another folder inside called "partials" that has other html files i'd like to render.

I thought it'd be self explanatory but searching through google I can't find the answer to this, but I'd like to render a file within the subdirectory as well.

I'm sure the answer is rather simple but I can't seem to find it..

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

var router = express.Router();    

//This Works
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

//This Works
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about');
});

//This Does NOT Work, How do I get this to work?
router.get('/partials/navbar', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('/partials/navbar');
});
```

Comment: Try removing the leading / from '/partials/navbar'

Comment: @MarkS. sigh...that worked.  u answered before O_Z if u want to submit the answer and i'll give u credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just remove the first `/` from  `res.render('/partials/navbar')`